# C++ unclear output

Tags: c++

I'm trying to find all the divisors of a number (n) and to add to the array those divisors that are at the 1st power (that appear only once), but I get in output just zeros, what's wrong with my code?

```
 #include<iostream>
 using namespace std;

 int k,A[100000],n,p,d=2,pozitia=0;
 int main()
 {
   cin>>n;

   while(n>1)
   {
     p=0;
     while(n%d==0)
     {
       p=p+1;
       n=n/d;
     }
     if (p==1) { A[pozitia]=d; pozitia++; }
     d=d+1;
   }

   for (int i=0;i<=pozitia;i++) cout<<A[pozitia]<<" ";
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: What do you see when you run it in the debugger?

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: thanks man, i know but i have problems with debuger, it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't follow your logic for computing the divisors. It seems to be much simpler than you make it out to be.

```
int stop = n/2 + 1;
for ( ; d < stop; ++d )
{
   if ( n % d == 0 )
   {
      A[pozitia]=d;
      pozitia++; 
   }
}
```

Here's a program that uses that logic.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void printDivisors(int A[], int pozitia)
{
   for (int i=0;i<pozitia;i++) cout<<A[i]<<" ";
}

void fun(int n)
{
   int A[100000];
   int d = 2;
   int pozitia=0;

   int stop = n/2 + 1;
   for ( ; d < stop; ++d )
   {
      if ( n % d == 0 )
      {
         A[pozitia]=d;
         pozitia++; 
      }
   }

   printDivisors(A, pozitia);
}

int main()
{
   int n;
   cin>>n;
   fun(n);
   return 0;
}
```

The output for input of `100`:

```
2 4 5 10 20 25 50
```

Comment: i need prime divisors

Comment: but it's okay, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You print always the same value:

```
for (int i=0;i<=pozitia;i++) 
    cout<<A[pozitia]<<" ";
```

It should be

```
for (int i=0;i<pozitia;i++) 
    cout<<A[i]<<" ";
```

Also pay attention that it should be `i<pozitia` and not `i<=pozitia` because you increment `pozitia` each time you insert a new value so at the end `pozitia` will point to a not initialized value in `A`.